# Errors when unit testing on Play Framework 2

Tags: java, exception, playframework, playframework-2.0, illegalstateexception

I encountered following exceptions when I was unit testing my playframework2 app.

> [error] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Error with models.Position field:finder
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate parameter types in public play.db.ebean.Model$Finder(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class)
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.scoreConstructors(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:106) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.createImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:21) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreateScalarDataReader(DefaultTypeManager.java:185) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:313) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:341) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:128) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>
> [error] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Error with models.ClubPosition field:finder
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate parameter types in public play.db.ebean.Model$Finder(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class)
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.scoreConstructors(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:106) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.createImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:21) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreateScalarDataReader(DefaultTypeManager.java:185) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:313) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:341) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
>       at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:128) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]

May I know, how could I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell for sure without the code for your models, but I have a suspicion that Position and ClubPosition are related via inheritance and in both of them you define a 'finder' field with the same name and identical type parameters.  Then they collide on compile.

Answer (score -1):

may be **finder** is declared without a modifier **statics** ?

I got the same problem when declared find without static modifier in my model.